# Is this a case of leakage or not?

Tags: data-leakage

I have a set of data on individuals' performance in 1960,1970,1980 and 1990, e.g. chess rating in those years for a bunch of players with 40-year careers.  I've been asked to build a model to predict 1990 performance based on history. So I built a model using all the data except 1990 as input and 1990 data as desired output.  Is this leakage given that I'm using 1990 data to predict 1990 data? If I split the data to train/test (with different individuals in train and test), will the test predictions be valid?

Comment: Do you have a time series or a set of discrete values (one for each decade)?

Comment: Its discrete values , e.g. chess rating in those years for a bunch of players with 40-year careers

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your problem is formulated as follows:

You have 3 independent variables (60, 70, 80) and you want to use those to predict the value of the 90's variable.

By training your model on all the players, the model essentially has already seen all possible inputs. It would be trivial for a good model to achieve an accuracy close to 100%.

In order to check your model fairly, you would need to keep some of the rows (players) "secret", and then use those as test samples to test your model with unknown data.

If you do this, you will have a much better picture on the performance of your model (with the tradeoff of having less training data). But it kind of is mandatory you do this, otherwise the results of testing on known (for the model) data is pretty much meaningless.

Update:
In case you are already doing train/test split, there still is a way to have leakage. If you make your predictions on the test set, and then use the insights you learned from this to change your model, this is indeed leakage.

There are two ways to combat this.
One way is to fix this by splitting the test set further into validation and test, make all of the procedures and fixes to your model using its validation accuracy as a measure of success and then (once you say "my model is ready") just do the final prediction on the test set to judge the performance on unknown data.

If your data are not that much and it is not very practical to further split it, you can also try doing cross validation on the training set instead.

Comment: yeah that's what i was doing -  test and train sets. the question is does that constitute leakage

Comment: Oh, the way your question is formulated made me think you hadn't done so. I will update my answer.

Comment: Does this answer you now?